# Vue Table how to align the numbers to right but just below the last character of the header

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, frontend

Right now my table is doing this.

```
+------------------------------+------------------------------+
|            Header            |            Header            |
+------------------------------+------------------------------+
|              Number(e.g 12.2)|                          13.2| 
+------------------------------+------------------------------+
```

The problem is that the header box has so many spaces in the left and right side of its content, so when I do align right, it shows badly.
What I want to show is the following effect:

[image]

Does someone know how to achieve this?

Comment: You can achieve this by using align center, whats the issue you are facing which using align center?

Comment: @chans for numbers in a table, it is recommended to align them to the right to make them easier to compare. Jing, maybe you can adjust the cell width to the content. This will make the header smaller. btw. on the screenshot it is difficult to see what you want to achieve